# Facebook iOS app install Ad conversion tracking

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ads-api

My client is running a Facebook Ad for app installs. He has shared the 
Facebook Ad with me.
I've added `FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()` inside `applicationDidBecomeActive` and created the Facebook developer app on the developer portal. I have also configured the XCode project in the right and recommended way. I can see the events being generated in the app analytics inside the developer portal. But, I can't prove that if any user clicks on the Facebook ad and installs the iOS app, the Facebook Ad manager will show up the count.

I've been following this guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/measuring/installs-and-in-app-conversions

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By using App Events for event tracking the count and value of these events will automatically attributed to your ad campaigns in analytics of facebook.

Comment: I reckon that happens automatically. But, how can I prove that to my client? He wants to see the download count incrementing in the Facebook Ad manager.